# Hash_map Error #erro C1189 C++ _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS

Tags: visual-c++

I'm having this problem:

[image: Image 1]

I've looked everywhere but I do not find a solution.

Comment: Have you even read the error? It tells you what can be done to ignore it.

Comment: How can I ignore it?

Comment: Add `#define _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRICATION_WARNINGS` somewhere near the top of your code ( `main.cpp`?)

Comment: I found, but the error continues = I read this in another topic

Comment: Please include your picture in the question not the link